# Resampling, removing duplicates by one column and getting all columns back

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

I have a table with 5 columns: date, time, event, email organization id. I want to remove the duplicate rows which have the same date, same time (the time can match upto + or - 30 seconds with the another time in the same date) and same event. I have resampled the data and removed duplicates for event.please see my code below. I now want to add back email address and organization id back to the resultant data. That means i want to find the unique combination of organization id, event id and email address and resample the data based on that. I have done only for event

You can see the event 'iti' is repeated with 30 seconds of each other at 2:29:40 and 2:29:50. So i have kept only one among these two values.
 I now want to add email address and organization id rows back to the resultant data. I want only those rows which match the corresponding event

Pictures of sample input and out put is given below

[The sample input and output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K8ryi.jpg)

Code so far

```
df=pd.read_csv('data.csv')

  Date          Time       Event    email   organization id
  12/15/2018    6:55:41     abc      kp     1035
  12/15/2018    13:36:39    def      pk     1036
  12/15/2018    14.21:56    com      lr     1040
  12/16/2018    2:29:30     pil      rm     1041
  12/16/2018    20:22:20    ati      as     1042
  12/17/2018    2:29:40     iti      ap     1040
  12/17/2018    2:29:30     esz      pg     1041
  12/17/2018    2:29:50     iti      ap     1040
  12/17/2018    9:04:03     ono      ar     1041
  12/17/2018    9:35:04     fac      sdh    1042
df1 = pd.DataFrame([' '.join([x,y]) for x, y in 
   zip(df['Date'],df['Time'])])
df1.columns = ['DateTime']
df1['DateTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['DateTime'])

df = df.join(df1)
df.set_index('DateTime', inplace=True)
outdf = df.resample('30S')['Event'].unique().to_frame()
outdf.columns = ['Events']
outdf = outdf.loc[outdf['Events'].apply(lambda x: len(x) > 0)]
df1=outdf['Events'].apply(pd.Series).stack().reset_index(level=1, drop=True).to_frame('Events')
df1['Date'] = df1.index.date
df1['Time'] = df1.index.time
df1
                   Events   Date    Time
DateTime            
2018-12-15 06:55:30 abc  2018-12-15 06:55:30
2018-12-15 13:36:30 def  2018-12-15 13:36:30
2018-12-15 14:56:00 com  2018-12-15 14:56:00
2018-12-16 02:29:30 pil  2018-12-16 02:29:30
2018-12-16 20:22:00 ati  2018-12-16 20:22:00
2018-12-17 02:29:30 esz  2018-12-17 02:29:30
2018-12-17 02:29:30 iti  2018-12-17 02:29:30
2018-12-17 09:04:00 ono  2018-12-17 09:04:00
2018-12-17 09:35:00 fac  2018-12-17 09:35:00
```

In this final output i want to add email and organization id.

Comment: don't link to files. Create a reproducible example with simpler code that gets your point across, show what you've tried so far, and show your expected output please.

Comment: ok..i am editing my question..

Comment: @MattW. i have edited my question

Comment: thanks for updating it. But I'm still a bit confused at what you're looking to do. You want to add email and organization id, but I don't see them anywhere in this, or what you'd like the output to look like. Would you mind adding that piece as well please?